# add text in shuffle package

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa, cocoapods

I've implemented a Shuffle package(https://cocoapods.org/pods/Shuffle-iOS), my main target is to create tinder like swap animation, Shuffle package really helped me, but I can only add images and swap them, what I want to do is to add a text label, and configure them with array which I've already created, but the documentation doesn't provide how to do that, I'm new to IOS, I understand some things, but some I don't, I tried to give property with string, created array and configured with delegates, but I can't see my Strings on view here's code below:

```swift
    let cardImages = [
        UIImage(named: "cardImage1"),
        UIImage(named: "cardImage2"),
        UIImage(named: "cardImage3")
    ]
    
    let texts = [
        "Hello","World","My"
    ]
    // gave function below string property
    func card(fromImage image: UIImage, fromText text:String) -> SwipeCard {
      let card = SwipeCard()
      card.swipeDirections = [.left, .right]
      card.content = UIImageView(image: image)
      
        
        let textLabel = UILabel() //created label here
      let leftOverlay = UIView()
      leftOverlay.backgroundColor = .green
      
      let rightOverlay = UIView()
      rightOverlay.backgroundColor = .red
      
      card.setOverlays([.left: leftOverlay, .right: rightOverlay])
      
      return card
    }
    func cardStack(_ cardStack: SwipeCardStack, cardForIndexAt index: Int) -> SwipeCard {
        return card(fromImage: cardImages[index]!, fromText: texts[index]) // configured card here
    }
```

If you have any addition question, feel free to comment.

Comment: please check below code

Comment: @RuchiMakadia please check the comments of your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can add text, labels, buttons, etc in shuffle

here is a code for that

```
func card1(fromJob Job: Job, index: String) -> SwipeCard {
    let card = SwipeCard()
    card.swipeDirections = [.left, .right, .up]
    card.layer.cornerRadius = 12
    card.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize.zero
    card.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0
    card.layer.shadowRadius = 6.0
    card.layer.masksToBounds =  false
    card.layer.borderWidth = 2
    
    let view_bg = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 16, y: 60, width: self.view.frame.size.width - 32, height: self.view.frame.height * 0.75))
    card.content = view_bg
    view_bg.layer.cornerRadius = 12
    view_bg.clipsToBounds = true
    
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1) { [self] in
        
        let view_bg1 = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view_bg.frame.size.width, height: view_bg.frame.size.height))
        card.content?.addSubview(view_bg1)
        
        let img_card_type = UIImageView(frame: CGRect.zero)
        img_card_type.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        img_card_type.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        img_card_type.isHidden = true
        view_bg1.addSubview(img_card_type)
        img_card_type.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalToSystemSpacingAfter: view_bg1.centerXAnchor, multiplier: 1).isActive = true
        img_card_type.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view_bg1.topAnchor, constant: 12).isActive = true
        img_card_type.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
        img_card_type.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 35).isActive = true
        
        
        let img_comapny = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 24, y: 24, width: 100, height: 100))
        img_comapny.image = UIImage(named: "icon_emploimi")
        img_comapny.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        img_comapny.layer.cornerRadius = 50
    
        img_comapny.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize.zero
        img_comapny.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0
        img_comapny.layer.shadowRadius = 6.0
        img_comapny.layer.masksToBounds =  false
        img_comapny.clipsToBounds = true
        view_bg1.addSubview(img_comapny)
        img_comapny.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: img_card_type.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        img_comapny.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view_bg1.leadingAnchor, constant: 24).isActive = true
        img_comapny.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
        img_comapny.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
        
        let lbl_company_name = UILabel(frame: CGRect.zero)
        
        lbl_company_name.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        lbl_company_name.numberOfLines = 3
        lbl_company_name.font = AppFont.getBold(forStyle: .title3)
        view_bg1.addSubview(lbl_company_name)
        lbl_company_name.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: img_comapny.trailingAnchor, constant: 24).isActive = true
        lbl_company_name.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view_bg1.trailingAnchor, constant: -24).isActive = true
        lbl_company_name.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalToSystemSpacingBelow: img_comapny.centerYAnchor, multiplier: 1).isActive = true
        
        let job_title = UILabel(frame: CGRect.zero)
        job_title.text = Job.title //"iOS Developer"
        job_title.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        job_title.numberOfLines = 2
        job_title.font = AppFont.getBold(forStyle: .title3)
        view_bg1.addSubview(job_title)
        job_title.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: img_comapny.bottomAnchor, constant: 32).isActive = true
        job_title.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view_bg1.leadingAnchor, constant: 24).isActive = true
        job_title.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view_bg1.trailingAnchor, constant: -24).isActive = true
        
    }
    
    let leftOverlay = UIImageView()
    let img_dislike = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: view_bg.frame.size.width - 132, y: 32, width: 100, height: 100))
    img_dislike.image = UIImage(named: "ic_dislike")
    leftOverlay.addSubview(img_dislike)
    
    let rightOverlay = UIView()
    let img_like = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 32, y: 32, width: 100, height: 100))
    img_like.image = UIImage(named: "ic_like")
    rightOverlay.addSubview(img_like)
    
    let upOverlay = UIView()
    let img_saved = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: (view_bg.frame.size.width - 100)/2, y: (view_bg.frame.size.height)/2, width: 100, height: 100))
    img_saved.image = UIImage(named: "ic_save")
    upOverlay.addSubview(img_saved)
    
    card.setOverlays([.left: leftOverlay, .right: rightOverlay, .up: upOverlay])
    return card
}
```

You can add view inside SwipeCard through the program and add labels and text in that easily.

Comment: Your code works fine, but the problem is that I've `UIView` with its own size( from storyboard), I want those cards width and height to be set to my `UIView`, I tried changing your code where you set `view_bg`'s width and height to `let view_bg = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 16, y: 60, width: mainView.frame.size.width, height: mainView.frame.height))`(`mainView` is my `UIView`) but it doesn't seem to work, the card is still out of my `UIView`